# Php PDO Get all column names from table in specific database

Tags: mysql, php

I currently have the following query. Which fetches all column names for a table. But when there are 2 tables with the same name (in different databases) it fetches those column names as well.

In the following query `$table` of course means the requested table. In this case for example `customer`.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns 
where lower(table_name)=lower(\''.$table.'\')
```

So my question is: How do I specify which database the query should look into.

Comment: What DBMS are we talking about?

Comment: I use PHPmyadmin

Comment: "PHPmyadmin" is not a DBMS.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Then it is MySQL

Comment: You should use the mysql CLI to do your database work. If a query fails there, then ask a question here. If it works there and fails in PHP or whatever tool you're using, then it's a programming question. Always ensure that it's not a database issue by using the mysql client first. Saves a lot of bother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL database is a synonym for schema. Subsequently, the information you're looking for is in the column `table_schema`:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns 
where lower(table_name)=lower(\''.$table.'\')
  and lower(table_schema)=lower(\''.$mydb.'\')
```

Comment: Awesome that works! I didn't understand how to filter on the database. Do you have a good recourse where I can read more about this?

Comment: The best resource is usually [product documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: And the use of `LOWER()` is probably redundant with what the collation will do.